# Problem with AudioTrack

Tags: android, audio, java-native-interface, android-ndk

Hello I wrote a program (on Android NDK), which gives audio buffer through JNI in Java. The problem of instability. Sometimes AudioTrack perfectly reproduces the buffer, and sometimes there are these messages:

`08-18 15:13:00.745: INFO/AudioTrack(12457): AudioTrack::set streamType[3] channels[12] format[1] sampleRate[44100]
08-18 15:13:00.749: INFO/AudioPolicyManager(2381): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 2 delayMs 0 force:0 
08-18 15:13:04.183: INFO/AudioHardwareALSA(2381): Output standby called!!. Turn off PCM device.`

Code in Java like this:

```
final int bufSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
track.play();
int byt = track.write(buf, 0, length);
```

In what may be a problem with this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `track.write` andf fill the minimum bufSize first before `track.play` is called.